# How to make sure the variable is not passed by reference

Tags: javascript, scope, pass-by-reference

I have this piece of code:

```
var A = [1,2,3];

function calculatePartialSum(A, i) {
 A.splice(0,i);
 console.log('calculating sum for ', A);
 return A.reduce(add, 0);
}

var add = function(a, b) {
 return a + b;
}

var test = function(A) {
 var sums = [];
 for ( var i=0; i < A.length ; i++ ) {
   console.log('calling calculate sum for i = ', i, A);
   sums.push(calculatePartialSum(A, i));
 }
 return sums;
}

console.log( test(A));
```

As you can see, the loop is executed two times because splice is modifying the Array `A`. What I don't get is why it is referencing A outside of the function scope.

1st Question: Shouldn't `calculateSum` have its own scope and not reference `A` that is defined outside of its scope?

2d Question: Admitting I don't understand how that's possible, what is an elegant solution in javascript that doesn't use the `JSON.parse` hack (for performance reasons) , neither external libraries?

Comment: why not simply copy it?

Comment: 1) The name `calculateSum` is misleading : one would expect this function to calculate the sum from 0 to `i` excluded i guess. 2) What is so wrong about writing a good old `for`loop in such a case ???

Comment: [JS does not have "pass by reference"](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html). It's always "pass by value", but in case of objects, that value is a reference.

Comment: So many good answers here - id like top mark them all as correct.

Comment: @GameAlchemist yes it is misleading. I renamed it to calculatePartialSum

Comment: ( What about `calculateSumFrom( array, startIndex)` ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy an `Array` with many methods, give a look to this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-copy/38) to see which method is faster.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
var myClone = clone( myArray );

function clone ( toClone ) {
    a = [];

    for ( i = toClone.length; i--; ) {
        a.push( toClone[i] );
    }

    return a;
}
```

it seems that the iteration is the fastest, but be aware of that if the elements in your array are `Objects` the will not be copied, but referenced.

```
var myArray = [{},{},{}];
var myClone = clone( myArray );
myClone[0].foo = 'bar';
console.log( myArray[0].foo ); // 'bar'
```

Comment: I mark this answer as correct, because of the jsperf link.
The fastest way to clone an array is `var a2 = array.length === 1 ? [array[0]] : Array.apply(this, array);`, which is 100 times faster than the for/loop, and 4 times faster than the slice() method (On my browser - Chrome 49.0.2623.63 on Linux x86_64 )

Answer (score 2):

In javascript when passing an array, the value of that array is a reference, that's why the function's `A` variable is the same as the outer scope `A` variable. You have to clone it to break the reference.

An easy way to clone an array is to use  `.slice();`

```
var B = A.slice();
```

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference. They are passed by value, but that value is a reference.

Comment: You're right, It was just easier to understand that way, but I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

1st Question: Shouldn't calculateSum have its own scope and not reference A that is defined outside of its scope?

Ans: `calculateSum` has its own scope and it is not operating on A defined outside. Its operating on A which is defined has parameter. However since, while invoking `calculateSum` you are passing reference of array instance A, both the A's are reference to same Array instance.

2d Question: Admitting I don't understand how that's possible, what is an elegant solution in javascript that doesn't use the JSON.parse hack (for performance reasons) , neither external libraries?

Ans: Use `A.slice();` to clone an array and then pass it to the function.

Answer (score 1):

> 1st Question: Shouldn't calculateSum have its own scope and not
>   reference A that is defined outside of its scope?

Yes, but you are passing the same object to that scope, just that reference is different.

> 2d Question: Admitting I don't understand how that's possible, what is
>   an elegant solution in javascript that doesn't use the JSON.parse hack
>   (for performance reasons) , neither external libraries?

Simply do this

```
console.log( test(A.concat([])));
```

or

```
console.log( test(A.slice(0)));
```

This will create a new object and pass to the `test` method.